# How do I use eclipse spring IDE to create a Spring boot application that runs on wildfly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I have my eclipse setup to use either wildfly or tomcat, but when I create a new spring-boot application, it defaults to tomcat, how can I change this? also, are there any other settings I'll have to modify? Everytime I configure spring core with jsf on wildfly there are a bunch of erros I have to deal with. I really don't like wildfly at all but have to use it for a new job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure you have installed `JBoss tools` plugin from Eclipse Marketplace.

Go right click on your project > Debug as (or Run as) > Run on server > Manually define a new server > Choose WildFly > Download and install runtime > Select desired version (i.e. WildFly 8.0).

Wait until WildFly downloads.

Next, next... Finish.. and your application should start on WildFly server.

Comment: run on server is not an available option, just run as java app or spring boot app